# How to construct a new HTML element in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, functional-programming, chaining

I have some code similar to this:

```
var glyph = isApple ? '<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-apple"></span>' : '<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-banana"></span>';
var newFruit = '<li class="list-group-item">' + glyph + '<span class="badge">' + score + '</span>' + name + '</li>'
$('#fruitList').append(newFruit);
```

Just a lot of gross concatenation that is hard to read and follow. Is there a way to functionally create these elements, and if so, how? Also, I'm curious of the speed of doing so, because if it is much slower than what I'm doing then I just won't bother.

I'm looking for something like this, for example:

```
var newElement = li().class("list-group-item").value(name);
newElement.span().class(isApple ? "glyphicon glyphicon-apple" : "glyphicon glyphicon-user");
newElement.span().class('badge').value(score);
$('#fruitList').append(newElement);
```

Now obviously the above is not good or probably even right but hopefully it gets the idea across. Basically a way of chaining functions to create new elements that avoids the mess of concatentations for creating custom HTML to insert.

Comment: What you might want if this is a common occurrence is to use a client side templating language like http://handlebarsjs.com/ or similar. Trying to write HTML using javascript is never pleasant.

Comment: $('#fruitList').append($(newFruit));

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```
$('<li>', {
        html: $('<a>', {
             href: item.href,
             text: item.title
        })
    });
```

This puts an `a` tag within an `li` tag. You can modify this as per your needs

Answer (score 1):

This structure should help, the trick is making sure the parent element is appended before the child:

```
var newElement = document.createElement('li');
$(newElement).addClass('list-group-item');
$(newElement).html(name);

$('#fruitList').append(newElement);

var newSpan = document.createElement('span');
var apple = isApple ? "glyphicon glyphicon-apple" : "glyphicon glyphicon-user";
$(newSpan).addClass(apple);
$(newSpan).addClass('badge');
$(newSpan).html(score)

$(newElement).append(newSpan);
```

Comment: no, all can be done in backstage and only need one dom insert with the master wrapper, also save $(elem) for multiple use instead of spamming it, but +1 for using pure js methods

Answer (score 0):

```
var $li = $("<li/>",{title:"woot"}).addClass("list-group-item").value(name);
$li.append( $("<span/>").addClass(isApple ? "glyphicon glyphicon-apple" : "glyphicon glyphicon-user") );
$("<span/>").addClass('badge').value(score).appendTo( $li );
$('#fruitList').append($li);
```

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, arrays are faster than string concatenation which is faster than DOM manipulation.

```
function getNewItemString(glyph,score,name){
   return [
      '<li class="list-group-item">',
      '<span class="glyphicon ',
      glyph,
      '"></span>',
      '<span class="badge">',
      score,
      '</span>',
      name,
      '</li>'
   ].join('');
}

$('#fruitList').append(getNewItemString('glyphicon-apple', 20, 'player1'));
$('#fruitList').append(getNewItemString('glyphicon-banana', 0, 'player2'));
```

Answer (score 0):

There is [an overload of the jQuery function](http://api.jquery.com/jquery/#jQuery-html-attributes) that allows you to do create an element and specify its properties. The following would replicate your example:

```
$('<li>', {
    class: "list-group-item",
    html: $('<span>', {
        class: isApple ? "glyphicon glyphicon-apple" : "glyphicon glyphicon-user"
    })
    .after($('<span>', {
        class: "badge",
        text: score
    }))
    .after(name)
});
```